# Oracle CASE short-circuit not working in group by

Tags: oracle, case, short-circuiting

I've found in the [documentation of case statment](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm) that it uses short-circuit:

> Oracle Database uses short-circuit evaluation. That is, for a simple
>   CASE expression, the database evaluates each comparison_expr value
>   only before comparing it to expr, rather than evaluating all
>   comparison_expr values before comparing any of them with expr.
>   Consequently, Oracle never evaluates a comparison_expr if a previous
>   comparison_expr is equal to expr. For a searched CASE expression, the
>   database evaluates each condition to determine whether it is true, and
>   never evaluates a condition if the previous condition was true.

But the following SQL is returning `divisor is equal to zero`:

```
WITH data AS (SELECT 1 AS cond, 10 AS num, 0 AS div FROM DUAL)
SELECT
  CASE WHEN cond = 2 THEN (CASE WHEN MAX(div) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(num / div) END)
       ELSE -1
  END AS result
FROM data
GROUP BY cond
```

Any solution to avoid `divisor is equal to zero` error?

**EDIT**

This query works fine:

```
WITH data AS (SELECT 1 AS cond, 10 AS num, 0 AS div FROM DUAL)
SELECT
  CASE WHEN cond = 2 THEN (CASE WHEN MAX(div) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
       ELSE -1
  END AS result
FROM data
GROUP BY cond
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
CASE WHEN cond = 2 
     THEN SUM(case when div = 0 then 0 else num / div end)
     ELSE -1
END
```

Comment: Thanks, really great and it also solved a problem to find div = 0 in second case (+1)