# Oracle is running my function in an SQL for data that is filtered out in the WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have an Oracle SQL statement which grabs some data, passing it to a function which returns a value. That function will raise an application error if the data it receives is invalid.

The function is raising an error because it is getting data that it shouldn't have, even though that data has been filtered out in the where clause (or through implicit inner joins).

Basically, it appears that Oracle is passing my data to a function before it is filtered out. How can I prevent this?

You can see commented out below the function that the query was running. The last predicate `AND WHSE.WIDX = 5632` makes this SQL return 0 results, however without it, that value is being passed to the `PAS.PAS_MERCH_PLAN.GET_WHSE_CUST_PRICE_SCHEME` function.

```
    SELECT
      DISTINCT WHSE.WIDX
    FROM
      AP21.STKAUD
    LEFT JOIN
      AP21.POZD
      ON POZD.POZDIDX = STKAUD.TRANIDX
    LEFT JOIN
      AP21.PORDD 
      ON PORDD.PORDDIDX = POZD.PORDDIDX
    LEFT JOIN 
      AP21.PORD
      ON PORD.PORDIDX = PORDD.PORDIDX
    INNER JOIN
      AP21.WHSE
      ON WHSE.WIDX = STKAUD.WHSIDX
   -- INNER JOIN
   --   AP21.REFCODE CURRENCY ON
   --   CURRENCY.RCIDX = PAS.PAS_MERCH_PLAN.GET_PRICE_SCHEME_CURRENCY(PAS.PAS_MERCH_PLAN.GET_WHSE_CUST_PRICE_SCHEME(WHSE.WIDX))
    INNER JOIN
      AP21.REFCODE WHSE_RC ON
      WHSE_RC.RCIDX = STKAUD.WHSIDX
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
      SELECT
        BUSDIV,
        WHSEIDX
      FROM
        AP21.GIT_MERCH_PLANNING_CONFIG PLAN_CONF
      UNPIVOT (WHSEIDX FOR WAREHOUSE_CODE IN (WHSE1,WHSE2,WHSE3,WHSE4,WHSE5))
    ) RETAIL_WAREHOUSE ON
      RETAIL_WAREHOUSE.WHSEIDX = WHSE.WIDX
      AND RETAIL_WAREHOUSE.BUSDIV = WHSE.REF1
    WHERE
      (
        WHSE.TYPE = 'R'
        OR RETAIL_WAREHOUSE.WHSEIDX IS NOT NULL
      )
      AND
      (
        STKAUD.TRANTYPE = '231' --TRANSFER OUT
        OR STKAUD.TRANTYPE = '32125' --STOCK WRITEDOWN
        OR STKAUD.TRANTYPE = '32124' --DIRECT STOCK TRANSFER
        OR (STKAUD.TRANTYPE = '210' AND COLUMN1 = 0 AND NVL(PORD.ARMS_LENGTH_DIRECT,0) <> 1 ) --WAREHOUSE PURCHASE ORDER RECEIPTS excluding Intercompany
        OR (STKAUD.TRANTYPE = '104' AND COLUMN1 = 0) --WAREHOUSE PRODUCTION RECEIPTS
      )
      AND TRANDATE >= TRUNC(SYSDATE-1)
      AND TRANDATE < TRUNC(SYSDATE-1)+1
      AND WHSE.WIDX = 5632
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can control what Oracle does when solving the query.

When presented with a query, it prepares an execution plan and it might decide to evaluate those values first, then filter at the end.

Perhaps if you modify your inner join adding that condition there as well it makes it apply that filter before calling the function?

```
...
INNER JOIN
AP21.REFCODE CURRENCY ON
WHSE.WIDX = 5632 
AND
CURRENCY.RCIDX = PAS.PAS_MERCH_PLAN.GET_PRICE_SCHEME_CURRENCY(PAS.PAS_MERCH_PLAN.GET_WHSE_CUST_PRICE_SCHEME(WHSE.WIDX))
...
```

Comment: I figured that would be the case, however was hoping there was a way to rearrange the query, or perhaps optimizer hints. The above won't work because the predicate `WHSE.WIDX = 5632` is not hardcoded, it was for the purpose of this question only. I could modify the function to just return NULL, however we want it to raise an error on legitimate cases.

Comment: Even if not hardcoded, you can't repeat it up there dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You can force short-circuit of conditions using CASE statement, e.g. write a function IS_VALID(widx)

```
INNER JOIN
AP21.REFCODE CURRENCY ON
CURRENCY.RCIDX = 
    CASE WHEN IS_VALID(WHSE.WIDX) = 'Y' 
    THEN PAS.PAS_MERCH_PLAN.GET_PRICE_SCHEME_CURRENCY(PAS.PAS_MERCH_PLAN.GET_WHSE_CUST_PRICE_SCHEME(WHSE.WIDX))
    END
```

Comment: Unfortunately even this method is not 100% reliable.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32202090/oracle-case-short-circuit-not-working-in-group-by) for an example where `CASE` short-circuiting does not prevent errors.

Answer (score 0):

A good way of ensuring that the function is only ever called for rows that meet the other criteria in the query is to put the rest of the query in a subquery, and call the function in the outer query, e.g.:

```
SELECT q.WIDX
FROM   (your query) q
JOIN    AP21.REFCODE CURRENCY
ON      CURRENCY.RCIDX
  = PAS.PAS_MERCH_PLAN.GET_PRICE_SCHEME_CURRENCY(
      PAS.PAS_MERCH_PLAN.GET_WHSE_CUST_PRICE_SCHEME(q.WIDX))
```