# How does Oracle perform OR condition validation?

Tags: sql, oracle, logical-operators

In Java, a logical OR condition behaves such that if the first condition is `true` then it does not evaluate the second condition.

For example:

```
int a = 10;
if (a == 10 || a == 0) {
    // Logic
}
```

Java does not evaluate the second test (`a == 0`) because the first condition (`a == 10`) is `true`.

If we have an Oracle SQL statement like this:

```
select * from student where city = :city and 
    (:age is null or age > :age)
```

How are `(age > :age or :age is null)` evaluated? If the parameter `:age` is `NULL`, then does it evaluate the second condition as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### PL/SQL

In PL/SQL, Oracle OR is another example of *short circuit* evaluation. Oracle [PL/SQL Language Fundamentals](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/fundamentals.htm#LNPLS258) says (in part)

> #### Short-Circuit Evaluation
>
> When evaluating a logical expression, PL/SQL uses **short-circuit evaluation**. That is, PL/SQL stops evaluating the expression as soon as it can determine the result. Therefore, you can write expressions that might otherwise cause errors.

#### SQL

However, in regular SQL, the OR *might* be evaluated in either order. As pointed out by [@JonHeller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/409172/jon-heller) in his comment *the expressions in this question are safe, more caution would be required if dealing with potential division by 0*.

Comment: Thanks for reply. so can u suggest that what is the best way to write below sql. (:age is null or age > :age) or ( age > :age or :age is null ). most of time :age is null.

Comment: I would suggest you test for `null` before testing a value, for the reason that it will evaluate to `true` first.

Comment: This is correct for PL/SQL but incorrect for Oracle SQL.  You cannot write expressions that might cause errors because you cannot rely on a left-to-right short-circuit evaluation.  For example, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32202090/409172).  Although the expressions in this question are safe, more caution would be required if dealing with potential division by 0.

Comment: @JonHeller Thank you. Edited.

Answer (score 7):

The database cost optimizer will consider many factors in structuring the execution of a query. Probably the most important will be the existence of indexes on the columns in question.  It will decide the order based on the selectivity of the test and could perform them in different order at different times.  Since SQL is a declarative and not procedural language, you cannot generally control the way in which these conditions are evaluated.

There may be some "hints" you can provide to suggest a specific execution order, but you risk adversely affecting performance.

Comment: It *is* possible to affect the evaluation order by the use of subqueries.

Answer (score 1):

Let Oracle decide for you. It will most of the time make a much better decision. In this case, there is even a construct that combines test for null with testing a value.

Replace

```
:age is null or age > :age
```

With

```
age > nvl(:age, age - 1)
```

Comment: the equivalent expression is `age > nvl(:age, age-1)`, isn´t it? anyway, this is a good advice :-)

Comment: -1 it is a really bad advice  to replace an expression by a more complex one. Oracle does the work for you if you have the OR expression  or does Oracle ask you how to eveluate it? If you introduce a function (NVL) now this expression his really difficult for oracle to optimize.  It now has to eveluate every row  to find out the value of the predicate. In contrast to this it didn't have to evaluate any row if :age was null and it wouldn't be able to use an index if age was not null.