# Oracle DECODE statement failing on RHEL but works on HPUX

Tags: oracle, select, decode

I've isolated a very specific code piece that works on our HP-UX Oracle 11.2 environment, but fails on our RHEL 7.1 Oracle 11.2 environment.  Any pointers as to why this would happen?

Everything else (except PSU level) is generally the same.

TIA

```
AND v_effective_date
    BETWEEN DECODE
          (pet.attribute1,'OVERTIMEVACCOMP',
              fnd_date.canonical_to_date(prv2.result_value),
              TO_DATE ('01/01/0001', 'DD/MM/YYYY'))
    AND DECODE
          (pet.attribute1,'OVERTIMEVACCOMP',
              fnd_date.canonical_to_date(prv3.result_value),
              TO_DATE ('01/01/0001', 'DD/MM/YYYY'))
```

Comment: Surely it's not a decode issue? Are you sure the fnd_date.canonical_to_date function returns the same value in both systems?

Comment: What does 'fail' mean - doesn't return the data you expect (in which case it's likely to be a data issue)? Gives you an error? Is the function valid, exactly the same for both environments,  and are you sure that isn't erroring (which can happen silently within a query) - if you call the function for every row in the table in a PL/SQL context does it report any errors? Environment-specific behaviour/bug is possible but unlikely.

Comment: Is this an Entity-Attribute-Value model that stores all data as a strings?  In some rare cases a `DECODE` or a `CASE` can evaluate expressions out of order or without short-circuiting.  Queries should not assume the `OVERTIMEVACCOMP` condition is checked before the function is called.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys, we've rewritten the code as follows:

Comment: Edit comments for only 5 minutes really?  Anyway...Thanks for the feedback guys, we've rewritten the code as follows "AND  DECODE (pet.attribute1,'OVERTIMEVACCOMP', fnd_date.canonical_to_date(prv2.result_value),TO_DATE ('01/01/0001', 'DD/MM/YYYY')) <= least (ABS.date_start,v_effective_date)" which works perfectly well.  This discounts a data issue.  I think Jon has the most probable answer in that the condition is not SYNCed within the query itself. An interesting observation which is probably very hard to prove and now I have to try to explain to management... :) Thanks Guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Entity-Attribute-Value models have a fatal flaw: stringly-typed data.

If all values are stored as strings it's critical that attribute filtering occurs before those values are converted into a type.  But Oracle's query optimizations make it almost impossible to enforce a specific order of operations in SQL.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32202090/oracle-case-short-circuit-not-working-in-group-by) has a simple example of how bizarre this out-of-order execution can get.  It's a bit extreme, but will hopefully help you prove how unpredictable order of operations can be.  You wouldn't think this query could fail, but it does:

```
WITH data AS (SELECT 1 AS cond, 10 AS num, 0 AS div FROM DUAL)
SELECT
  CASE WHEN cond = 2 THEN (CASE WHEN MAX(div) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(num / div) END)
       ELSE -1
  END AS result
FROM data
GROUP BY cond;

ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero
```

We don't know exactly how Oracle implements the order.  Maybe it's different between RHEL and HPUX, maybe it's different on Thursdays.  Unfortunately, even using a `LEAST` may not be bullet-proof.  That function may *logically* operate in order, and it may *normally* use short-circuit evaluation, but it's not guaranteed to always run in that order.  You may have just switched between one 99.9% solution to another 99.9% solution.

There are only two fool-proof solutions to this, discussed in more detail in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31769013/409172).  Either change the table to use a different column for different types or add an inline view with a `ROWNUM` to every query.  Neither of which is pleasant.